# How to break the build if test coverage fails minimum threshold?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, scoverage

We want to fail the build on codeship if test coverage goes below the threshold value. But it is not failing the build.

Scoverage Plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.3.5")
```

Added following two statements in build.sbt

```
coverageMinimum := 80,
coverageFailOnMinimum := true
```

It is not failing even in local if test coverage is below 80. The command I run is

```
sbt clean coverage test coverageReport
```

Comment: This looks ok... Do you have an example online?

Comment: @ValyDia Example as in? I just run sbt clean coverage test coverageReport. And i expect it should break if coverage fails minimum threshold.

Comment: Sorry I am meant a minimal project that reproduces it

Comment: Without example project which exposes the problem we will not be able to help.

Comment: @GrzegorzSlowikowski Thanks for the reply but the problem has been resolved after updating the plugin version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try upgrading to version [1.5.1](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/releases/tag/v1.5.1) like so

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")
```